# How to prevent an overloaded function from being called with the wrong argument types

Tags: typescript, overloading

I want to generate typescript definitions for some JS code which is a bit awkward because some classes have static methods with the same name as their parents' static methods but different type signatures. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992314/typescript-bindings-for-classes-with-methods-that-shadow-a-parents-methods-with) and [here](https://github.com/sammydre/ts-for-gjs/issues/12#issuecomment-510500415).

My attempt at a solution is to use a generic overload like this:

```
export class Parent {
    ...
    static new(arg1: string): Parent
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    ...
    static new(arg1: number, arg2: number): Child
    static new<T, V>(arg1: T): V
}
```

This could be abused by calling the generic form with an arbitrary type for T, causing undefined behaviour. Is there a way to prevent that? Typescript insists on all overloads with the same name having the same visibility, so I can't make the generic one private. But if there's no way of restricting calls to one of the signatures with fixed types it seems like we've missed out on one of the best benefits of overloads.

Comment: TypeScript makes the static side of class inherit from the static side of parent classes, [as per ES6](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628#issuecomment-149333638).  This has a bunch of good and bad effects, and if you expect to be able to change the signature of a method on the subclass constructor, you'll have a bad time.  There might be some verbose declaration tricks which will help you here, but they will not be simple

Comment: You really want a static method named `new`?   I will change that to `method` in my answer

Comment: Yes, pseudo-constructors as static methods are common in gjs because of the way GObject C code is designed. I think this is partly because C doesn't support overloaded function names and partly because most other OOP languages don't allow constructors to call virtual functions. Natural JS constructors are included in the public API though; at first I thought this would be a problem for the clever approach in your answer, but then I saw you have provided your objects with `new` methods, which can be used as constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do with the overload signatures, TypeScript has decided that static methods will inherit from parent classes ([as possibly implied by ES2015](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628#issuecomment-149333638)), so you can't just extend a class and work around this.  At least until and unless TS ever changes.  For example:

```
namespace Original {
  declare namespace Classes {
    class Parent {
      static method(arg1: string): Parent;
      parentProp: string;
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
      static method(arg1: number, arg2: number): Child;
      static method<T, V>(arg1: T): V;
      childProp: string;
    }
  }

  const child = new Classes.Child();
  const parent = new Classes.Parent();
  const alsoParent: typeof parent = new Classes.Child();

  const childConstructorMethod = Classes.Child.method;
  const parentConstructorMethod = Classes.Parent.method;

  // the following inheritance should hold
  const alsoParentConstructorMethod: typeof parentConstructorMethod = childConstructorMethod;
  // which leads to this even without generics
  alsoParentConstructorMethod("oopsie-daisy");
}
```

That is similar to your classes, and you can see that the above will end up letting people call the parent-signature method on the child constructor no matter what you do... because one can assign the child static method to a variable of the type of the parent static method.  That's inheritance, and it places a restriction on things that you can't work around with signatures.

---

So what can you do?  I'd consider changing the declared types so as not to use `class` at all.  Note that this doesn't mean the JS can't use `class`; it just means that the best way to represent this sort of relationship is with your own types and values.  For instance:

```
namespace PossibleFix {
  declare namespace Classes {
    interface Parent {
      parentProp: string;
    }
    export const Parent: {
      method(arg1: string): Parent;
      new (): Parent;
    };

    interface Child extends Parent {
      childProp: string;
    }

    export const Child: {
      method(arg1: number, arg2: number): Child;
      new (): Child;
    };
  }

  const child = new Classes.Child();
  const parent = new Classes.Parent();
  const alsoParent: typeof parent = new Classes.Child();

  const childConstructorMethod = Classes.Child.method;
  const parentConstructorMethod = Classes.Parent.method;

  // now there is no implied inheritance on the static side
  const alsoParentConstructorMethod: typeof parentConstructorMethod = childConstructorMethod;
  //    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- error! not assignable

}
```

This is nearly identical to the original `class` based type.  A `class` has an instance side and a static side.  Here, the instance side becomes an `interface`, and the static side becomes an exported `const` variable which is both a constructor (`new():...`) and has the method.  But here, even though the instance side inherits (we still have `Child extends Parent`), the static sides are now unrelated to each other.  And that allows you to pick any signatures you want on the methods of the child constructor.

This will end up being more verbose, especially if you have actual TypeScript code that was generating the original declarations, since now you have to come up with a way to assert that the generating code conforms to the latter declarations, and it could be messy.  But, it gives you more freedom.  Hopefully that helps a bit.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYdAGyQG8AoJJAEwnjxDWVElgWQGEaopojSylqQOSAAq0IwAC7devKOJDiM8JJHEALAPbkAFLSwBGAFxJZmYFgCURkXQkBuHtLg3xQtOphGTuLPekBfYgc+digkFlUMPHIkCAAPcTFyUOsxSRJpMll5RWUINU0dNH0jYABXMAAjCDQAGiRdACYS8qq0SzCIqN8MrIUlFQ1yAB4AFTqANQA+QuKkEfbx7ul4TvJXd09xUx8ggLIAnnh1YFk+VaQAXiRgCAB3MJDoADpwyO1zbqOTySdUy+u7g8BJwoE8UhItB9DsdTiA8FB1ODxEZxABPGAQdQAMyQvwk-xu9zYwOeryikPs0O+ZzeLBhW1K8HE6jQAFk8oN-sSOKTVk8BppPvTcaIJHTvmhGcy2RzNFzHqCkfzZeRKWQAPTqpBqZBY9R4PDqW7eJC4VTVDByYCIYwaUpRJAaKJU2HwxGi8TikxSlns-LkFHozE4vGe+mSpm+lX-Fa08M+mX+7qapC3CIrJB4CAgJLa9TaiKhCAANzEqctdskWDEFvgUB4cIRSK9DMjicGWgAROp3FAMBAALTkEAYKCoztQg4MaBwG1CdQcDAVLMAMQwsSkFCoNDo13AM+YQJ5oXSvFwCTQWMPSM3jg96w8xi23iWSD2vDiMBZki+pyRRlPaQBW0XRDCfbZ2iRV8yEJJBISsD1Xz8NUzwkaorxtMlojiBJgFzG9AN4WMogfTZtiQwJpE-b8+GFLCAKCMhgJmMCykqao6kaZp2LaIwsOggF7ngjo3iQ7oDjIX8f3OK5YO5EEXlWCkXR+D0CUBeTniRZTJOFRt3WcQMMWxEVnHUokFUUt5lJUmkohbCNpT9Tkrk00EsOVJNbNDByE2cuVXMspVgJQlNgCNAtqmQUdrnzDAwBgPB+2iM0LStG1jkip9siUPtKFs-Tm3jNt-IDbUgxMnziqc6MrmI8hfJKlVky1XgAD8Os6rrup6nqkCGAcBxiNA3DQABCWLJGBbBQGXCBAgCIA)

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. At the moment I'm contributing to someone else's project, so I don't know whether such a big change would work for them. At the moment they ignore inheritance altogether and duplicate properties from parent classes in the children instead, because this static method inheritance issue caused them problems in the past. I don't know whether they tried something similar to my approach and it has a flaw I haven't noticed yet. Old issue comments imply that they've also tried interfaces instead of classes in the past, but probably not with your twist of namespaces.

Comment: I ran into a hiccup for the case where a pseudo-constructor is called `new`: Defining `new` as `new(): Child` defines a constructor, not a static method, so I wouldn't be able to use `const child = Child.new()` as needed. But if I define it as `new: () => Child` instead it works. And both forms can be defined simultaneously, nice.

Comment: You can also do `"new"(): Parent;` (surround the method name in quotation marks) if you need the compiler to treat it as a method (and not as a function-valued property... those are mostly equivalent but the compiler does distinguish methods from function-valued properties in a few cases)